# Get Subscriber Object Profile Attribute Type

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way to get the subscriber object's profile attribute *type*? From my understanding, it should either be a date, a number, or text.

We're currently using FuelSDK-PHP and the SOAP API to import attributes from a subscriber object into our system (among other things), but we'd like to be able to know what the datatype is for the attributes we're importing.

I can easily try to parse the string values of the attributes as a date, and a number, but it would be nice to get the answer straight from ExactTarget.

I've looked at [this page](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/profile_and_preference_attributes/) but it doesn't seem to have anything to do with any ExactTarget APIs.