# Get Subscriber Profile Attribute Types

Tags: marketing-cloud, api

The same question has been asked [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50586/get-subscriber-object-profile-attribute-type) but went unanswered.

I'm trying to determine the dataTypes of the subscriber profile attributes seen in the Marketing Cloud UI under "Profile Management".  Judging by the UI there are three types (numeric, text and date).

I've tried using the two methods below:

Method 1, described [here](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_profile_attributes_on_the_subscriber_object/), retrieves all of the attributes I'm looking for but only contains name and value information.

Method 2, described [here](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/describing_a_subscriber/), contains dataType information under the "extendedProperties" field but only profile attributes I've created personally show up.  I.E. the "Full Name" profile attribute that was created by default by Marketing Cloud doesn't show up at all.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just treat them all as text?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.

Even if it was, the only three options are `Text`, `Numeric` and `Date`.

[image: Profile Attribute data types]

It's SQL Server behind the scenes, so it'd be `varchar`, `int` and `datetime2`.

Profile Attributes are also available in [**Query Activities**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) in Enterprise 2.0 accounts from the [**_EnterpriseAttribute**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_enterpriseattribute/) data view, so if you needed them in specific datatypes, you could write them to specifically typed Data Extension and retrieve them with the API from there.

Perhaps if you could give us some insight into why it's needed we could suggest another solution.